# Representing an optimization program as a quadratic program with linear constraints.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am trying to convert this minimization problem:

$$
\text{minimize}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N, z \in \mathbb{R}}. \sum_{m=1}^M \text{max} (\mathbf{a}_m^T x, z) + \tau \Vert x \Vert_2
$$

to a quadratic program with linear constraints. How can I go about this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a new variable $y_m$ to represent the $\max$ and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
y_m &\ge \mathbf{a}_m^T x \\
y_m &\ge z \\
\end{align}